# How to perform anova based on mean, sd and n to get statistical significance and Tukey

Tags: r, anova, p-value, tukey

I am trying to get a significance value using ANOVA based on mean, sd, and n. I tried the following code, however, it could not find the function "ind.oneway.second". I tried installing "rpsychi" but the package is not available. Please let me know if any other way to get it done.

```
library(rpsychi)

E_data <- read.csv(file = "E.csv", sep = ",")
with(E_data, ind.oneway.second(E_data.mean,E_data.sd,E_data.n))
```

error:
could not find function "ind.oneway.second"

```
Example Data structure:
strain  hrs    mean   sd      n
alpha   12hrs  0.06   0.0010  2
beta    12hrs  0.08   0.0020  2
delta   12hrs  0.22   0.0030  2
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a CSV file that contains column samples, mean, sd, and n values. I am looking to calculate the p-value and Tukey based on these values. I am wondering if ANOVA test can calculate the significance values based on mean, sd, and n OR is there any other way to calculate the significance p-value? Let me know if it helps to understand my question or if I should provide more details.